# Can't call type() from within PDB under Python 2.7

Tags: python, pdb

```
p type("ddd")
*** TypeError: TypeError("'int' object is not callable",)
!print(type("dd"))
*** TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
type
255
!type
255
```

Does anybody know why this is? It doesn't appear to be a PDB command. Due to its name, searching for answers hasn't been successful.

Comment: Naturally, a question was asked that was thought to be relevant in general, and a couple of holier-than-thou people sought to suppress this.

Answer (score 4):

Post your code.  It looks like you overwrote the name `type` with your own value, which happens to be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

`type` is not a PDB command or normally unavailable during a debug session. You must have a local variable `type` with an integer value in your local or global namespace:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.run('None')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) type
<type 'type'>
(Pdb) type = 255
(Pdb) type('ddd')
*** TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Local variable defined in the code-under-test:

```
>>> pdb.run('type = 255; None')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) type
255
```

The work-around in these cases is to refer to the original `type` function via the `__builtins__` module:

```
(Pdb) type('ddd')
*** TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
(Pdb) __builtins__.type('ddd')
<type 'str'>
```